# Como projetar uma imagem no telão?

Tags: c#, winforms

Já procurei na internet e não acho.

Como faço para projetar uma imagem no telão ?

Exemplo: Na tela principal(notebook) mostrar executável(windows forms), e na segunda tela mostrar uma imagem (não mostrar windows form). É como se fosse um powerpoint.

Parecido assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como chama isso? Eu não acho na internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um projetor não passa de uma outra saída de vídeo. Pode pressionar <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> para alternar entre os dispositivos de vídeo conectados. Não sei se funciona no Windows 7 ou inferior.

Tenha um formulário com o que quer mostrar. Uma imagem, um texto ou o que seja. Esse será o `ApresentacaoForm`.

Basta mostrar esse formulário normalmente, só ajustando sua posição, para que fique na sua segunda tela.

```
ApresentacaoForm formulario = new ApresentacaoForm();
Screen[] telas = Screen.AllScreens;
Rectangle bounds = telas[1].Bounds; // pode ser outro índice.
formulario.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
formulario.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
formulario.Show();
```

Documentação de [Screen.AllScreens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx) na MSDN.

Para você não ter um formulário para cada imagem, deixe um formulário com o componente de imagem e passe no construtor do `ApresentacaoForm` o caminho para essa foto, *setando-a* no componente.

Se tiver dificuldades para achar o dispositivo correto, pode filtrar o vetor de `Screen` pelo `DeviceName`.

```
Screen projetor = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DeviceName == "Meu projetor");
```

Comment: +1 otima resposta - ps: usei sua sugestão do `FirstOrDefault` pra facilitar pegar o dispositivo, melhor que ficar iterando :D