# Como saber se a tela está no modo de "Estender"?

Tags: c#

Quero fazer um `if` para saber se a tela está no modo de "Estender".

Exemplo: (Win + P)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer isso em C#:

```
if (?) // só pode entrar no if, se a tela está no modo "Estender".
{
    SegundaTela formulario = new SegundaTela();
    Screen[] telas = Screen.AllScreens;
    Rectangle bounds = telas[1].Bounds; // pode ser outro índice.
    formulario.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    formulario.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    formulario.Show();
}
```

Comment: Não há maneira de se fazer isso apenas com .NET, você vai precisar chamar a API C++ do Windows. Mas qual é o seu objetivo com isso? Talvez detectar o modo da tela seja desnecessário, se tudo que você quiser for algo como projetar em uma tela específica.

Comment: @Renan, Fiz uma pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245514/como-projetar-uma-imagem-no-tel%C3%A3o  de como projetar o telão. Por isso eu fiz a pergunta aqui para saber se PC está no modo "Estender", porque se usuário não escolher na opção de estender, a segunda tela (formulario) não vai mostrar no telão, por exemplo.

Comment: De alguma maneira preciso mostrar um aviso para ativar no modo "Estender".

Comment: Acho que pode ver o tamanho da tela, se estiver estendida, a segunda tela não vai ter x=0

Comment: É só um palpite... Vou fazer um teste

Comment: Serviria forçar o "estender"?

Comment: Sim, pode ser @vnbrs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta verificar se há mais do que uma `Screen`:

```
if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
{
 //Estendido
}
else
{
 //Duplicado, ou apenas 1 tela
}
```

> Você não especificou, mas esse código é para `winforms` porque a classe Screen deriva de `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Isso funciona mesmo? Eu jurava que a contagem de telas era a mesma independente do modo, pois mesmo com a replicação de telas, cada uma pode ter resolução, área e profundidade de bits diferentes.

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui, até me surpreendeu porque mesmo estando no modo duplicado, a contagem de telas passa a ser apenas uma.

Comment: Nesse caso +1, isso é genial.

Comment: Projetos WPF podem utilizar System.Windows.Forms sem problemas

Comment: Funciona mesmo, LOOOOL

Answer (score 3):

Desconheço algo pronto do .NET para utilizar o "Estender" do Windows. Talvez conseguirá com a [API do Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx).

Em Windows 7, Windows 8 e 10 pode utilizar o DisplaySwitch.exe do sistema com o argumento `/extend`. Para as outras versões do sistema terá que testar. Não sei se o <kbd>Win + P</kbd> já era atalho no Vista.

```
var processo = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "DisplaySwitch.exe", Arguments = "/extend" } };
processo.Start();
```

Além do `/extend`, existem outras formas de apresentação. Pode utilizá-las com os argumentos:

- `/external`: somente a segunda tela;
- `/internal`: somente a tela do computador;
- `/clone`: duplica as telas.

Comment: Após fazer isso dá pra forçar a aplicação a aparecer em um monitor específico. BTW +1.

Comment: Dá erro: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado'

Comment: @vnbs ,Windows 10.

Comment: Ta falando do `DisplaySwitch.exe` ?

Comment: @Renan não só a aplicação, mas todas, pq isso modifica o que se está usando no sistema como se fosse utilizar o Win + P

Comment: @vnbrs, gostei a idéia de forçar para "Estender".