# Como abrir processo externo no segundo Monitor

Tags: c#, processo

Estou precisando abrir um programa externo para ficar na segunda tela. Preciso que fique exatamente encaixado no segundo monitor.

Vamos supor que quero abrir o bloco de notas, não quero abrir ele no primeiro monitor, e sim no segundo monitor. Esse é o meu objetivo.

Estou pegando as informações da segunda tela para mover o notepad para ela. Perceba que a segunda tela está em forma de `array[1]`, esse `array` é a informação da segunda tela extendida. Para executar o código abaixo, precisa estender a tela e deixa o notepad aberto.

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  Rectangle area = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;
  ScreenMove(area.X, area.Y, area.Width, area.Height);

 }
 [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

const uint SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
const uint SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;

public static void ScreenMove(int x, int y, int lx, int ly) {
 IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("Notepad", null);
 if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero) {
  SetWindowPos(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, x, y, lx, ly, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
 }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É isso que não consigo, deve ter alguma forma para mover a janela do notepad para a segunda tela, mas não sei qual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
[Flags]
public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

    /// <summary>
    ///     If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues, the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window. This prevents the calling thread from blocking its execution while other threads process the request.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents generation of the WM_SYNCPAINT message.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Draws a frame (defined in the window's class description) around the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function. Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to the window, even if the window's size is not being changed. If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE is sent only when the window's size is being changed.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Hides the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not activate the window. If this flag is not set, the window is activated and moved to the top of either the topmost or non-topmost group (depending on the setting of the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Discards the entire contents of the client area. If this flag is not specified, the valid contents of the client area are saved and copied back into the client area after the window is sized or repositioned.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set, no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent window uncovered as a result of the window being moved. When this flag is set, the application must explicitly invalidate or redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Same as the SWP_NOOWNERZORDER flag.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents the window from receiving the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Displays the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,

    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
}


public static bool MoveToMonitor(IntPtr windowHandle, int monitor)
{
    monitor = monitor - 1;
    return WinApi.SetWindowPos(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, Screen.AllScreens[monitor].WorkingArea.Left,
     Screen.AllScreens[monitor].WorkingArea.Top, 1000, 800, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOZORDER | SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_NOREDRAW);
}

var p = Process.Start("notepad");
MoveToMonitor(p.MainWindowHandle, 2);
```

Agradeça ao [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750113)

Comment: Bruno Onde consigo a classe WinApi?

Comment: @sYsTeM oops esqueci-me dessa dependencia. Está aqui https://github.com/alex-tomin/Tomin.Tools.KioskMode/blob/master/Tomin.Tools.KioskMode/WinApi.cs

Comment: Certinho agr, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

sYsTeM, você precisa saber se a máquina tem dois monitores... Use "System.Windows.Forms":

```
if (Screen.AllScreens.Length > 1)
{
 //Estendido
}
else
{
 //Duplicado, ou apenas 1 tela
}
```

Veja em:

[Como saber se a tela está no modo de “Estender”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247640/como-saber-se-a-tela-est%C3%A1-no-modo-de-estender/247656)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas tipo, o que coloco dentro do primeiro IF?

Comment: No primeiro IF você coloca o código para apontar para a outra tela. Para fazer isso, você precisa mudar o posicionamento do form.

Comment: Como mudo o posicionamento do Form? É que sou leigo nisso :(

Comment: Err... é... no caso de um "CALL" ou algo assim para um programa externo... não sei se tem como passar algum "parâmetro" para o Windows reposicionar na tela. Sorry...

Comment: Espere! Tive uma ideia, mas é preciso testar. Veja a propriedade: "ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow", ela inicia o processo em uma nova janela... será que é possível controlar a posição dessa nova janela? Veja: Process.Start Method - https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2