# Como projetar window2 na tela secundária do wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Segue código (MainWindow):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

var win2 = new SegundaTela();
Screen s2 = Screen.AllScreens[1];
Rectangle r2 = s2.WorkingArea;
win2.Top = r2.Top;
win2.Left = r2.Left;
win2.Show();
```

Está mostrando na tela primária e não secundária. Alguma solução ?

Já fiz uma pergunta com `winforms` aqui: [Como projetar uma imagem no telão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245514/como-projetar-uma-imagem-no-tel%C3%A3o)

Answer (score 2):

Talvez o `Screen.AllScreens[1]` esteja pegando a primeira tela ao invés da segunda, poderia experimentar `Screen.AllScreens[0]`, ou fazer exatamente semelhante a [resposta do @vnbrs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245516/3635), mas ao invés de usar `DeviceName` iria usar o `Primary`

```
Screen tela2 = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(f => !f.Primary );
```

Uma ideia, do qual não estou certo, seria verificar qual monitor esta rodando o seu Form principal e então pegaria o `DeviceName`, usando [**`Screen.FromHandle`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromhandle(v=vs.110).aspx), supondo que o esteja dentro da class aplicaria o `this`, seguindo a sugestão do do [**@MatheusMiranda**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10140768/1518921), acaso queira passar o Window:

```
Screen principal = Screen.FromHandle(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
string nomedispositivo = principal.DeviceName;
```

Acaso vá passar um elemento dentro do Window, seria assim com [**`Screen.FromControl`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.screen.fromcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Screen principal = Screen.FromControl(<form vai aqui>);
string nomedispositivo = principal.DeviceName;
```

Então para pegar a outra tela faria isto:

```
Screen tela2 = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DeviceName != nomedispositivo );
```

Comment: @MatheusMiranda pode usar `if (Screen.AllScreens.length > 1) { ... }`, assim saberá se tem projeto ou outra tela